# How to render multiple hyperlink controls in a datagridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a requirement to implement data in a windows forms grid where one of the column needs to show multiple links for each datarow like google.com, bing.com, msdn.com and so forth seperated by comma. And, hovering on each of this link must show respective description about it. I'm not sure how to implement it. Do I have to embed any custom user control inside the column. Please recommend a possible workaround if this is not an easy task.

DataGridViewColumn with CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() renders with no issues but it's just a comma seperated list of string. I need to render as hyperlink and so, the commented code below, is what renders as System.Collection of Generic List.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Links", typeof(string));
            foreach (var data in myList)
            {
                string lnk = string.Empty;
                if (data.Link != null)
                {
                    lnk = string.Join(",", data.Link);
                }
                addRow["Links"] = lnk;
            }
            DataGridViewColumn linkCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
            linkCol.DataPropertyName = "Links";
            linkCol.Name = "Links";
            linkCol.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGridview.Columns.Insert(2, linkCol);



            //DataGridViewLinkColumn linkCol = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            //linkCol.DataPropertyName = "Links";
            //linkCol.Name = "Links";
            //linkCol.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            //linkCol.HeaderText = "Link(s)";
            //linkCol.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            //linkCol.TrackVisitedState = true;
            //linkCol.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            //dgvImportDataErrors.Columns.Add(linkCol);
```

viewLink1, viewLink2, viewLink3.
Hover on each link must show the description

Comment: You need a custom control, which contains a flow panel and a list of child LinkLabel controls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=netframework-4.8